# Physical interpretation to Strichartz estimate

Tags: analysis, inequality, mathematical-physics, strichartz-estimates

Good morning everybody. **I'd like to do a qualitative question about the Strichartz estimate**. Let me recall it.

Let $u$ be the solution of the Schrodinger equation:

$$
i \partial_t u + \Delta u = f(x)
$$
with initial data $u(0) = \phi \in H^1(\mathbb{R^d})$.

If the following relation of indexes holds
$$
\frac{2}{q} + \frac{d}{r} = \frac{d}{2}
$$ 
then the following inequality is true:
$$
|u|_{L^q_t L^r_x} \leqslant |\phi|_{L^2_x} + |f|_{L^{q'_1}_t L_x^{r'_1}}
$$
where $q_1$ and $r_1$ is a couple of Strichartz indexes and $q'_1, r'_1$ satisfie the relation:
$$
\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{q'} = 1.
$$

My question is not at all technicall, infact is really clear to me how the proof works and why these estimates are so usefull.

**I really would like understand what is the physical meaning of these kind of inequality (if it exists) and how can I give an interpretation to these results with the probabilistic point of view of the solution as probability density for the position of the particle.**

I think that a starting point is to consider the inequality given by the couple $q = + \infty$ and $r = 2$ (this couple works for every dimension!). I think it is very important since it gives an uniform bound in time of the integral of the density.

$$
1 = |u|_{L^{\infty}L^2} \leqslant |\phi|_{L^2_x} + |f|_{L^{q'_1}_t L_x^{r'_1}}
$$

This kind of inequality seems like full of information about some constraints between initial data and the potential (or something linked to it).

I've deeply studied the NLS and a lot of property of the structure of this equation but even in the Tao's books and cannot find any interpration to the huge amount of developed technologies.

Ciao 
AM